# How to check if user has checked captcha checkbox ssjs ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have this below form. How i can check if the user has clicked the captcha checkbox and display an error if user has not checked the captcha checkbox.

Regards

Comment: Sid ampscript questions are welcome here, but you definitely need to give us some more info to go by. What is your code and what parts of it are you not sure about ? If we don't know what your tried AND where you are stuck it's hard for us to help. Could you try updating your question again ?

Comment: Hi .. Do u have any examples like how to get response from google captcha using ampscript..